# System of 3 equations in 3 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$182 = 2ZY + 6WY$

$95 = 2ZY + 2WY$

According to my solution and even an online calculator $Y$ equals to $3.625$ if $W = 6$ but if I plug in to the equations it doesn't give the correct answer. I have no idea what is wrong.

give that $Z=W-1$ therefore $182 = 2WY - 2Y +6WY$ and $95 = 2WY - 2Y +2WY$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

We start with the system of equations:
 $$ 2ZY + 6WY =182\tag{1}$$
 $$  2ZY + 2WY=95 \tag{2}$$

Subtract $(2)$ from the upper equation $(1)$ to get:

$$4WY=87$$
Subtract $(2)$ three times from $(1)$ to get:
$$-4ZY=-103$$

We now use that $W=Z+1$ and rewrite the upper equation:

$$4(Z+1)Y=87$$
$$-4ZY=-103$$
We then proceed by distributivity and notice a common term in both equations:

$$4ZY+4Y=87$$
$$-4ZY=-103$$

Now we add these two equations again to cancel the factor of $4ZY$:

$$4Y= -16 \rightarrow Y=-4$$ We now can find the other variables quite easily from $$4WY=87 \rightarrow W=-\frac{87}{16}$$
$$4ZY=103\rightarrow Z=-\frac{103}{16}$$

Also see wolfram alpha:
[image]

Comment: in my case W = Z+1, so i need to find Y

Comment: see my edits please

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: so $Y = 87/4W$ which is going to be 3.625 if W = 6. correct ?

Comment: Yes but we can calculate $Y$ explicity has to be $-4$, so $W$ cannot be $3.625$.

Comment: if my statement is correct and i plug it back in tot the original equation it is not gonna be true. try it your self.

Comment: It should satisfy all three equations simultaneously.

Comment: ubtract the second on three times from the first to get:
−4ZY=−103 didnt get it substract from where?

Comment: You have two equations right? you subtract them from each other.

Comment: Subtracting two equations means if $a=b$ and $c=d$ then we can also say that $a-c =b-d$.

Comment: But you can also say that if $a=b$ and $c=d$ then $a-3c = b - 3d$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively for the reader that is not familiar with subtracting equations, we could use substitution:
 $$ 2ZY + 6WY =182\tag{1}$$
 $$  2ZY + 2WY=95 \tag{2}$$
$$W=Z+1 \tag{3} $$

We first isolate $Y$:
 $$ Y(2Z + 6W) =182$$
 $$  Y (2Z + 2W)=95 $$
$$W=Z+1 $$

We now use the third equation to simplify for $W$:

$$ Y(2Z + 6(Z+1)) =182$$
 $$  Y (2Z + 2(Z+1))=95 $$
We simplify some more:
  $$ Y(8Z+6) =182$$
 $$  Y (4Z + 2)=95 $$
We expand the brackets again:
 $$ 8YZ+6Y =182$$
 $$  4YZ + 2Y=95 $$
So we may also write that:
 $$ 8YZ+6Y =182$$
 $$  8YZ + 4Y=190 $$
So this also means that if we bring a term of $6Y$ to the other side:
 $$ 8YZ=182-6Y$$
 $$  8YZ + 4Y=190 $$
We then substitute the upper expression for $8YZ$ into the lower equation:
$$ (182-6Y)+ 4Y = 190 $$

So now, after simplification and some algebra:

$$-2Y=8 \rightarrow Y=-4. $$

Comment: Do you get this alternative derivation?  especially the algebraic steps at the end?